# ERROR : Android NDK build error

Tags: android, android-ndk

I've been facing this for many days. I tried every thing but I don't understand where I went wrong. This error keeps coming up.

```
Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-24 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 8 in ./AndroidManifest.xml    
make: Entering directory `D:/Android/androidProjects/face-detection/openCVSamplefacedetection/src/main'
jni/Android.mk:8: ../../sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk: No such file or directory
make: Leaving directory `D:/Android/androidProjects/face-detection/openCVSamplefacedetection/src/main'
make: *** No rule to make target `../../sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk'.  Stop.
:openCVSamplefacedetection:ndkBuild FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':openCVSamplefacedetection:ndkBuild'.
```

> Process 'command 'ndk-build.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
>   Information:BUILD FAILED

this is build.gradle

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
sourceSets.main {
    jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs' //set .so files directory to libs
    jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
}

// call regular ndk-build(.cmd) script from app directory
task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
    if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
        commandLine 'ndk-build.cmd', '-C', file('src/main').absolutePath

    } else {
        commandLine 'ndk-build', '-C', file('src/main').absolutePath
    }
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
}





compileSdkVersion 11
buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "org.opencv.samples.facedetect"
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 8

    ndk {
        moduleName "detection_based_tracker"
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile project(':openCVLibrary249')
}
```

and this is local.properties

```
ndk.dir=D\:\\Android\\android-ndk-r12b
sdk.dir=D\:\\Android
```

Comment: Do you have `ndk.dir` specified in the local.properties file?  Also, show your build.gradle in the question....

Comment: Does "../../sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk" exist? Note that paths are relative to "D:/Android/androidProjects/face-detection/openCVSamplefacedetection/src/main'
jni/"

Comment: @DanAlbert yes OpenCV exist in jni folder

Comment: In which know folder? There are two mentioned here.

Comment: @DanAlbert D:\android data\OpenCV-2.4.9-android-sdk\sdk\native\jni

Comment: Then "../../sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk" doesn't exist. Like I said, that path needs to be relative to your Android.mk file, and it looks like it isn't based on the error message.

Comment: @DanAlbert i didnt understand this :(